# Leetcode 31. Next Permutation - Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to solve a Leetcode problem:

**Implement next permutation, which rearranges numbers into the lexicographically next greater permutation of numbers.
If such an arrangement is not possible, it must rearrange it as the lowest possible order (i.e., sorted in ascending order).
The replacement must be in place and use only constant extra memory.**

I don't understand why I am getting an error saying "list index out of range" on line 17 (i marked as "error"). Test cases were all working.

```
class Solution:
    def nextPermutation(self, nums: List[int]) -> None:
    
        # pivot
        r = len(nums) - 1
        while nums[r-1] > nums[r] and r > 0:
            r -= 1
        pivot = r 

        if pivot == 0: 
            nums.sort()
            return 

        # swap
        else: 
            swap = len(nums) - 1
            while nums[pivot-1] >= nums[swap]: # error (line 17)
                swap -= 1
            nums[pivot-1], nums[swap] = nums[swap], nums[pivot-1]

            # reverse
            nums[pivot:]  = sorted(nums[pivot:])
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], which people can just run to get the according error. Also, I guess this is Python, so please [edit] your question and add that tag.

Comment: I actually wasn't able to find a particular test case that produced the above error. The error I see is from the leetcode editor which is frustrating for me too

Comment: Errors like that sometimes correspond to edge cases such as lists of length 1

Comment: Try this input - `[1, 1, 1]` and see what's happening?  Single item - `[1]`  does not cause this problem.

Comment: @DanielHao Found it! [1, 1, 1] is producing that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate issue is that `swap` can become less than `0`, for inputs like `[1, 1]`, to prevent this change:

```
while nums[pivot-1] >= nums[swap]:
```

to:

```
while nums[pivot-1] >= nums[swap] and swap >= 0:
```

Furthermore, you also want to use `>=` rather than `>` in your pivot calculation loop, so that, you don't prematurely exit the loop when two adjacent elements are the same (e.g., `[2, 1, 1]`) i.e., change:

```
while nums[r-1] > nums[r] and r > 0:
```

to:

```
while nums[r-1] >= nums[r] and r > 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
    def nextPermutation(self, nums: List[int]) -> None:

        # pivot
        r = len(nums) - 1
        while nums[r-1] >= nums[r] and r > 0:
            r -= 1
        pivot = r 

        if pivot == 0: 
           nums.sort()
           return 

        # swap
        else: 
             swap = len(nums) - 1
             while nums[pivot-1] >= nums[swap] and swap >= 0:
                swap -= 1
             nums[pivot-1], nums[swap] = nums[swap], nums[pivot-1]

             # reverse
             nums[pivot:]  = sorted(nums[pivot:])
```

Try this code using Python 3 format at Leetcode you will pass..